# Using Jenkins for load tests

Tags: testing, jenkins, automation, jmeter

I'm using JMeter for load test and want to integrate my testing with Jenkins for automated testing.

I'd like to use Jenkins for two things.

1. I have one big script and several scenarios which only deviate in number of threads and ramp-up time. I'd like jenkins to use a master script, edit these two variables, and run my scenarios in sequence.
2. These scenarios produce log files, which on completion I'd like to move and rename with a counter on the end (must be unique) ex. JMeter_Load_{COUNTER}

Can/should I do this with Jenkins, or should I just use scripts and crontab?

Thanks for any insights on this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Jenkins allows having [parameterized builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) so you can pass arbitrary parameters to a Jenkins job which will trigger JMeter tests.
2. Using approach from point 1 you can configure JMeter to append i.e. Jenkins build number or build ID to the .jtl results file. See [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) wiki page for all the available options

For more infomation on JMeter and Jenkins integration check out [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) guide

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it meets your 2nd case, however you could consider having a look at the Jenkins Performance Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin).